# Databinding NoSuchMethodError with buildtools 3.4.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-databinding, nosuchmethoderror, android-studio-3.4

When using the latest DataBinding

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0-alpha10'
```

A `NoSuchMethodError` crashes the app upon Activity load. Using:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
```

causes the databinding to work successfully.

Here's the crash:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>
(Landroidx/databinding/DataBindingComponent;Landroid/view/View;I)V in 
class Landroidx/databinding/ViewDataBinding; or its super classes
(declaration of 'androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding'
```

Is there any way around this if we want to use the latest build tools?

Comment: Do you have `androidx` in the project? The reason may be, that `3.4.0-alpha10` uses `androidx` for data binding and therefore crashes.

Comment: We are using androidx in this project.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue with an external library which uses data binding + AndroidX on `3.4.0-beta05` build tools. `3.3.1` works just fine.

Comment: @JacobFerrero it will be fixed in 3.4.1

Answer (score 12):

One of your libraries relies on data binding and is distributed with generated data-binding classes built with build tools 3.3 (or earlier). The issue is caused by the breaking change introduced in the latest beta/rc version of the data binding lib. In version 3.4 the signature of `androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding` constructor has been changed from:

```
protected ViewDataBinding(DataBindingComponent bindingComponent, View root, int localFieldCount)
```

to:

```
protected ViewDataBinding(Object bindingComponent, View root, int localFieldCount)
```

Which makes any generated data binding class binary incompatible with 3.4 databinding lib, resulting in the following exception upon startup:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Landroidx/databinding/DataBindingComponent;Landroid/view/View;I)V in class Landroidx/databinding/ViewDataBinding; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding' appears in /data/app/com.example.idolon-LqF2y8dUMxZoK3PVRlzbzg==/base.apk)
        at com.example.lib.databinding.ActivityLibBinding.<init>(ActivityLibBinding.java:20)
        at com.example.lib.databinding.ActivityLibBindingImpl.<init>(ActivityLibBindingImpl.java:30)
        at com.example.lib.databinding.ActivityLibBindingImpl.<init>(ActivityLibBindingImpl.java:27)
        at com.example.lib.DataBinderMapperImpl.getDataBinder(DataBinderMapperImpl.java:316)
        at androidx.databinding.MergedDataBinderMapper.getDataBinder(MergedDataBinderMapper.java:74)
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.bind(DataBindingUtil.java:199)
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.bindToAddedViews(DataBindingUtil.java:327)
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:306)
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:284)
```

As a workaround you can rebuild libraries that contains data binding classes using the latest build tools.

The corresponding bug on Androig Bug tracker is: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122936785

**UPDATE**
The issue has been fixed and the fix is available in 3.5 beta 1 (it will also be available in the upcoming 3.4.1)